# how to convert timedelta64 to number of days integer?

Tags: python, numpy

I have this `146 days 12:37:08.787241` but I want just number of days in integer. For some reason when I  `df['days'].astype(int)` it's giving me an error

`cannot astype a timedelta from [timedelta64[ns]] to [int32]`

but `astype` seems to be the solution for many other people

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a single value, you can use [`Timedelta.days`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timedelta.days.html)

```
td = pd.to_timedelta('146 days 12:37:08.787241')
td.days
146
```

However, for a pandas `Series` of Timedeltas you'll need the [`dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dt-accessor) accessor

```
my_pd_series.dt.days
```